# scipy function evaluation callback

Tags: python, scipy, callback, evaluation

I am using scipy.optimize.minimize(). I see that that it does many function evaluations within one iteration. How do I save all the evalutations?
I use callback, but it only saves one value per iteration, while I need all function evaluations.

(The code that I am using, but it does not save all function evaluations

```
def cost_function(x):
    '''some function'''

history = []
def callback_f(x):
    y = cost_function(x)
    history.append([x,y]
output=minimize(cost_function,x0,method='l-bfgs-b',callback=callback_f)
```

)

Comment: how about having `cost_function` doing its own save?  `callback` clearly says it's called after each iteration.  That's a reasonable behavior, given that one function is to stop iteration early.